# SignalR: Client side JS functions are invoked using WebSockets but not when Long polling

Tags: websocket, signalr, long-polling

I am using new SignalR-Server for ASP.NET Core. When I have my transport set to WebSockets then it works flawlessly, but when I switch it to Long Polling (by disabling websockets on server side) then SERVER SIDE methods are invoked but when server tries to call client side method nothing happens. Does anyone have an idea what the problem might be?

Edit:
I noticed that when I call
 Clients.All.setBasicRoomInfo
instead of
 Clients.Group(sessionRoom.RoomId).setBasicRoomInfo
it works fine. So problem is with groups somehow.